# Salesforce Lookup Object Relationships

Tags: salesforce, lookup

I have a number of objects that contains references to other objects in Salesforce. An example is that a Shipping is the parent object related to ShippingItem by the shippingId. In order to save ShippingItems I need to get the ShippingId of the Shipping object. Also, the ShippingItems are related to ShippingMethod object which contains the shipping methods, UPS, FEDEX etc. This is a picklist type that allows users to pick the shipping method. In order to create/save  the ShippingItem. I need to obtain all the related fields, i.e. ShippingMethod i.e UPS, ShippingId to which it is related and other similar information. How can I obtain these fields in order to save the ShippingItems? When I inspect the Objects, I am unable to determine the fields to query in order to obtain the related information.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, ShippingItem has a lookup to Shipping and a lookup to ShippingMethod. Are you providing a UI where people create ShippingItems? If yes then ShippingID and ShippingMethodID should be populated on the shipping record when you get the record back in controller. 
If your question is how to provide a list of ShippingMethod records on the UI for users to select, you can query the object records separately and create a picklist for the user to choose. 
Adding a little more information or code snippet will help you get better answers.

Comment: I am developing a solution which doesn't directly interact with the Salesforce app.  I am interacting with SalesForce using connectors, i.e. objects that allow you to query Salesforce objects. However, I don't know how to find out from Salesforce, what fields in the parent object link to the child object, so I can make the query.